# Javascript append string between math operations

Tags: javascript, string, math

```
items = 3;
$('#div').html(items + 1 + ' - ' + items + 3);
```

Trying to make `#div` display `4 - 6`, but it instead shows `4 - 33`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why it happened:

first the parser reads `items + 1`, so fine and dandy, it's `4`

then it concatenates with `' - '`, so now you have `4 -`

then it sees `+ items`, at this moment, you are dealing with `String`, so it concatenates with 3 (as `items` is 3), so you have `4 - 3`

then you have another concatenation with `3`, but the left operand is a `string`, so the right operand is type casted into `String` as well, so you have `4 - 33`

To achieve what you want, you need to enclose the inner operations:

```
$('#div').html((items + 1) + ' - ' + (items + 3));
```